jQuery - submit form after preventdefault
I've looked at lots of suggestions but none of them are working for me.
The form has two submit buttons, one for add .add and the other for cancel .cancel
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" class="add">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Cancel" class="cancel">

I'm using the following jquery to do an ajax request and depending on the result I want an alert or the form to submit.
$('body').on( 'click', '.add', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
$.ajax({
    #do ajax request, 
    success: fucntion( res ) {

       if ( res.length >= 1 ) {
         alert ( res )
       } else {
         #submit form here
       }

   }
})

I've tried:
$('input[type="submit"]').submit()
$('.add').submit()
$('.add').trigger()

But it fails to submit the form.
Adding some debug to the if / else I can see it is at the correct part of the script.
Any idea how I get this to work ?
Thanks

You need to create a minimal reproducible example

tour current code should work: https://jsfiddle.net/ydhze1gb/  (but for sure use form submit). So you need to share more details like I said previously. create a minimal reproducible example

I got this working using the following:
$('body').on( 'click', '.add', function (e) {

    if ( ! $(this).data('complete' ) ) {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        $.ajax({
            #do ajax request, 
        success: fucntion( res ) {
            if ( res.length >= 1 ) {
                alert ( res )
            } else {
                $('.add').data('complete', true).click()
            }
        }
        })
    }
})

Thanks

<form id="myForm" action="submit_handler.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myForm').on('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // Stop the default form submission

                // Perform your custom validation or actions here
                let isValid = true; // Replace with actual validation logic

                if (isValid) {
                    // Manually submit the form if validation passes
                    this.submit();
                } else {
                    // Handle validation failure (e.g., show error messages)
                    alert('Validation failed. Please correct the errors and try again.');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>


If I was to solve the same problem above I would use a different approach, my approach is highlighted below.

I would wrap the inputs in a form

Select Reset as the input of the second input

Add an event listener to the form

Prevent default event of the form

Run the Ajax call
 <input type="submit" class="add">
 <input type="reset" class="cancel">



// load jquery script
<script>


$('#form').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault()

    $.ajax({
        //.....
    })



})
    

</script>


it wont work, because on submitting the form, the control again goes that click event, e.preventDefault() makes its stop from further executing, if there is no preventDefault(), it functions like a recursion, calling again and again the same one.
I am glad that you found the answer
